# PHP script that will find a replace %{variable_name}%

Tags: php, variables

I've seen systems use a method that you type in `%{variable_name}%` in your text (lets say to store in a database or send a mass email), and when the page loads, it finds `%{variable_name}` and replaces it with another piece of code/string.

For instance in sending a mass email to mailing list: `Hello %{name}%`, this is an email....and when click submit, it will send the email except it will be... "Hello John Doe, this is an email"...

I've searched google and can't find it because I don't really know what its called either.  I've just seen this in code and I'm currently writing a code that it would be extremely useful.

If someone could tell me what its called, what to search for, or an example of how to implement it, that would be fantastic.

(and if I put the wrong tags in this, please change to the right ones)

Comment: You could simply use str_replace to replace the tags with a value.

Comment: [Templating engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_engine_(web)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am successfully using this approach:

```
 $message = str_replace('[NAME]', $name, $message);
```

So that `[NAME]` in for instance a mass email is replaced by the contents of `$name`

If you prefer the syntax you have then `%{NAME}%` is replaced by the contents of `$name` by:

```
$message = str_replace('%{NAME}%', $name, $message);
```

You can redo it as many times you want, say you want to add a specific link and an email address:

```
$message = str_replace('%{NAME}%', $name, $message);
$message = str_replace('%{LINK}%', $link, $message);
$message = str_replace('%{EMAIL}%', $email, $message);
```

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: So lets say if I wanted to have one called %{name}%, would I type the string replace just like yours or would it be `$message = str_replace('%{NAME}%', $name, $message);`

Comment: You are awesome..I was actually about to ask about multiple when I saw your edit.  Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use str_replace: http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

```
    <?php
        $string = "Your %variable_name% sentence..";
        $new_string = str_replace("%variable_name%", "beautiful", $string>");
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a class for you:

```
class templatevars{
    private static $vars=array();
    public static function set($var,$val){
        self::$vars["%{".$var."}%"]=$val;
    }
    public static function replace($text){
        return str_replace(array_keys(self::$vars),array_values(self::$vars),$text);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
templatevars::set("varname","text to insert");
templatevars::set("varname2","other text to insert");
echo templatevars::replace("First: %{varname}% Second: %{varname2}%");
```

If you want multiple replacers, remove all static classifiers from the class, and:

```
$replacer_1=new templatevars();
$replacer_1->set("var","text");
$result=$replacer_1->replace($text_source);
```

Comment: What is the difference between what yours does and a basic str_replace does?

Comment: Mine has two advantages:
-Can store variable/value pairs for reuse
-Has a slightly better performance with high number of var/val pairs as it calls str_replace just once independently from the number of the var/val pairs

Comment: If you have time, can you tell me how I'd use your class to do the following.... Lets say I have a mass mail tool and I want to query all the people who are on our mailing list and send them this message,  `Hello %{first name}%, this is a mass mail` where it searches the database of profiles where mailing list = yes, and then sends them an email with their first name in it...I know how to do the email and query, but how would I incorporate your class into that?

Comment: `while ($record=mysql_fetch_object($your_query_result)){
    templatevars::set("first_name",$record->firstname); //in $record->first_name first_name is the name of the field in your table that stores first names
    $body=templatevars::replace($your_email_body_template);
    //use mail or whatever email sending function here providing $body as the email's body
}`

Or if you use mysqli use mysqli_fetch_object($result) or $result->fetch_object()

Answer (score 0):

Found this on PHP.net

[str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)